# Which development package in Ubuntu 13.10 has ndir.h?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, configure, tmux

I am trying to build tmux 1.8 statically on Ubuntu 13.10.

I am using the command `LDFLAGS="-static"  ./configure`.

The error on the command line:

```
checking for library containing setupterm... no
configure: error: "curses not found"
```

The error I get in the `config.log` file is

```
configure:4401: checking ndir.h usability
configure:4401: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:59:18: fatal error: ndir.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ndir.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
```

I Googled around for `ndir.h` and found http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/i386/bash-builtins/filelist, so I did `apt-get install bash-builtins` which completed successfully but did not help.

Answer (score 3):

aptitude install libevent-dev libncurses-dev pkg-config

Comment: Just a clarification for anyone coming here to find solution for "ndir.h: No such file or directory" error.
This has nothing to do with libcurses or libevent.


According to [this article](https://unixpapa.com/incnote/header.html), the file ndir.h and it's variation (dirent.h, sys/ndir.h, sys/dir.h) is part of glibc. You should have one of those four files in your system already.

Comment: yes sys/dir.h is included with glib.c but it has a dependency on dirstream.h which is not included in any base package.  ndir.h is now in emacs and dirstream.h is now in apt.  Why would directory structures not be part of the base OS!!!  I must be wrong somehow but that is what it seems like.